# Why do I sing to my plants?

Tags: viridi

In Viridi you can sing to your plants, what is the purpose of this?

Does it increase the speed at which the plant grows? Or perhaps the quality of the plant? If so by how much?

Or does it not do anything beside adding to the relaxing atmosphere of the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plant's status will be improved.

A plant's status is either *Thirsty*, *Sated* or *Overwatered*. *Sated* is the optimal status which singing will cause the status to head towards.

For more information take a look into [this beginner's guide from the steam community](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=504773762)